# Not able to see anything in the https://jwt.ms when set as a reply url in Azure SignupSignin user workflow

Tags: azure, azure-ad-b2c

I am trying the Azure ADB2C based on articles and videos. Followed the steps and I have configured the properties for user flows as well. When I click on the Run user flow, it opens up the sign up sign dialog, I add a user with the details. Once the user is added, it goes to my reply url https://jwt.ms.
Based on the url in the browser, I felt it should have worked. But for some reason, the boxes are shown empty.
The url that I see is...
https://jwt.ms/?code=eyJraWQiOiJjcGltY29yZV8wOTI1MjAxNSIsInZlciI6IjEuMCIsInppcCI6IkRlZmxhdGUiLCJzZXIiOiIxLjAifQ..EiDn2BjcA8xTRac1.2pNAFLdcbOupozfuKIC8T9VXmL4zz8iEisf6PsNyxDYzVJcl2vfwwrtMpqJvsC-xeSPyrHUgVpdblKiVfILllrOsWj7MJbTX0QNlzPEAItTGoRow3A2F4FWBR7Y28PQcxeZwa05SMpKhoNutdmnRq-usM7VMc0eYXjJ2JXTSc1piwYf14Na5We9arijagkmVvHFBDLDnjaVBUixEF5_dTGWAjnwAXRIII-plBZBoFZCZ2XtdSLu5LYWSJXBxuA5lqDaVN3OHLOP92VZkNRgB97UPIO3aSe9s44XEEGe5COpTWhzxoOXy53ydnCG8xZwYFKA_J54hGdKLGZrE-BYOW0sU7Dcevq1iwaBqJ3K3CwM6s9o6zCwsAf2pUlAuXYfwk8kA9SKi0fmNiUsSskWhUgiJTPSlqq_woWPGgX3JZpiHTDNbOCA5VUgToEYmDgReOb4M-MeCSCcKWb315vP3UPgzE1LpRet1AFMGqcNznUd8jkP39uaRdLDDP5VAZy7pmeN-GPQJYCcyfdJCRJc1yPoiRYM4SdBUecQTioRkZ95l0y1ANZ3yYSB6eAV_B83KL4EdSIM.e3NVLoGCNXgfloDFbzZimg

Could some one help me understand why the token is not being shown in the browser?
[image]

Please Note: The user is created with No issues. its just the reply of token that I see as issue.

Answer (score 5):

Found the cause of the issue.
I had to enable the Implicit grant for both Access tokens and ID Tokens for the app I created.

[image]